# Slider in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make the same slider as in the photo. What would be round buttons. I used the `flutter_slidable` plugin, but it doesn't work or am I doing something wrong?
[image]

Below is the code I was trying to do

```
       Slidable(
                  endActionPane: ActionPane(
                    motion: const DrawerMotion(),
                    children: [
                      SlidableAction(
                        onPressed: (BuildContext context) {},
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(180)),
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icons.delete,
                      ),
                      SlidableAction(
                        onPressed: (BuildContext context) {},
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180),
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icons.delete,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("Text",
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      subtitle: Text("Text2"),
                      onTap: () {
                      }));
```

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work? Show us your code of what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code I've written it works exactly as you wanted:

```
Scaffold(

  backgroundColor: Color(0xffF3F3F6),
  body: Center(
    child: Slidable(
      key: const ValueKey(0),
      startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const ScrollMotion(),
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              elevation: 2.0,
              fillColor: Colors.red,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              shape: CircleBorder(),
            ),
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    fillColor: Colors.red,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                  ))),
        ],
      ),
      child: const ListTile(
        title: Text('Slide me'),
        tileColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: No problems... :)